# Problems with ros::package::getPath in Fuerte

Tags: roslaunch, ros-fuerte, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something like the following used to work in electric but in fuerte it incorrectly yields /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslaunch/bin/roslaunch instead of /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/roslaunch

```
std::string roslaunch_path = ros::package::getPath("roslaunch");
sprintf (roslaunch_bin_path, "%s/bin/roslaunch", roslaunch_path.c_str ());
```

In electric

```
$rospack find roslaunch 
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch
$ls /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/bin/roslaunch
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/bin/roslaunch
```

In Fuerte

```
$rospack find roslaunch 
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslaunch
$ls /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslaunch
manifest.xml  resources
```

Is this the desired behavior? If so how do we find the location of the roslaunch binary? Is there a roslaunch API that is stable so we don't need to exec() roslaunch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29931/problems-with-ros::package::getpath-in-fuerte/) by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 403 on 2012-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, it looks like the solution is to use execvp() instead of execv().

I am vaguely uncomfortable not specifying the full path, but since nothing is setuid or setgid I suppose it is a reasonable solution.

---

Originally posted by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) with karma: 403 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be a result from [REP122](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html)/[REP124](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0124.html).

Why can't you just call `roslaunch` or maybe `rosrun roslaunch roslaunch`?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1